# python function error : Type Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi im fairly new to python and cant spot my error in this program, my error looks like this

> TypeError: hitormiss() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'totalaim'

```
#!usr/bin/python3
import random

def takeshot(prompt='do you want to take shot?\n'):
answer = input(prompt)
    if answer == ['yes', 'y']:
        print("taking shot...")
    else:
        print("not-working")

def cal(randomnum = random.randrange(0, 100) , baseaim = 15):
    totalaim = randomnum + baseaim
    return totalaim




def hitormiss(totalaim, hit=50):
    if totalaim >= hit:
        print("You have hit your target!")
    elif totalaim < hit:
        print("You have missed your target!")
    else:
        print("Revise Code.")



takeshot()
cal()
hitormiss()
```

Is totalaim not already declared in cal?

Comment: No it's not. It is declared locally to `cal` only. Plus you seem to be confusing classes and functions and many more things. Maybe you should start with a tutorial?

Comment: thank you for the refresher! yeah that might be due to the constant stream of studying python for the last three days, just so much information to take in.

Comment: And please be aware that the value of the parameter `randomnum` in your `cal` function will only be calculated once. After that you'll always get the same number. If you don't want that you'll have to move the creation of `randomnum` to the body of the function.

Comment: @Matthias thank you will keep this as reference! i just read a tutorial that said i could specify the parameters when making the function so i just wanted to use it!

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but they are only evaluated once during compile time, not during runtime. So if you have a fixed value it's OK, but in this case (or if you are using a mutable value like a `list`) it will lead to undesired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, `cal.totalaim` won't resolve in the way you're planning

```
def hitormiss(totalaim, hit=50):
    if totalaim >= hit:
        print("You have hit your target!")
    elif totalaim < hit:
        print("You have missed your target!")
    else:
        print("Revise Code.")
```

And then call, as suggested

```
takeshot()    
hitormiss(cal())
```

Comment: thank you! rookie mistake by me. i apologize ive been spending so much time recently trying to learn python that its too much information to retain at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `cal()` and `hitormiss()` function call and replace it with:

```
hitormiss(cal())
```

This is because a parameter has to be passed to `hitormiss()` and `cal()` returns the `totalaim` value.